# JS sync and async onclick functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, button, onclick, synchronization

I've been struggling with this issue lately.
I'm not sure if it has any connection to "sync/async" functions in JS. If it does, I would be more then thankful to understand the connection.

I've been making a simple component function:
There's a button "next","back" and "reset". Once pressing the matching button, it allows moving between linkes, according to button's type.
The links are an array:

```
const links =  ["/", "/home", "/game"];
```

Here is the component:

```
function doSomething() {
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = React.useState(0);
  const links =  ["/", "/home", "/game"];
  
  const handleNext = () => {
  setActiveLink((prevActiveLink) => prevActiveLink+ 1);
};

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveLink((prevActiveLink) => prevActiveLink- 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveLink(0);
  };

  return (

            <div>

            <button onClick={handleReset}>
            <Link className = 'text-link' to = {links[activeLink]}> Reset</Link>
            </button>

            <button onClick={handleBack}>
            <Link className = 'text-link' to = {links[activeLink]}>Back</Link>
            </button>

             <button onClick={handleNext}>
            <Link className = 'text-link' to = {links[activeLink]}>Next</Link>
            </button>
            </div>
```

When I'm trying to put the `activeLink` in the "to" attribute of Link, it puts the old value of it. I mean, handleNext/ handleReset/handleBack happens **after** the link is already set; The first press on "next" needs to bring me to the first index of the links array, but it stayes on "0".

Is it has to do something with the fact that `setActiveLink` from `useState` is sync function? or something to do with the Link?

I would like to know what is the problem, and how to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Link`s seem to be navigating to a new page?

If so, the `React.useState(0)` gets called each time, leaving you with the default value of 0.

Also your functions `handleNext` and `handleBack` aren't called from what I can see.

Comment: It's navigating into another route(defined in app.js), but the buttons appear at all pages. When I console log the value of" acitveLink" it's always 1 under the needed value: when I expect "2" it hold "1" etc. The functions are called whenever the button pressed